# How to add tags to a web services reference in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I am using the web service interface in .NET via http://api5.silverpop.com/SoapApi?wsdl. For Silverpop's ExportList request, the tags within the query only allow the standard properties i.e. LIST_ID, EXPORT_TYPE, EXPORT_FORMAT, ADD_TO_STORED_FILES, DATE_START and DATE_END; however I need to the send additional COLUMN properties as part of my request. I’m trying to find out how to extend the reference file to support the additional fields.

Standard/default Properties:

```
<Envelope><Body>
<ExportList>
<LIST_ID>56008</LIST_ID>
<EXPORT_TYPE>ALL</EXPORT_TYPE>
<EXPORT_FORMAT>CSV</EXPORT_FORMAT>
<ADD_TO_STORED_FILES/>
<DATE_START></DATE_START>
<DATE_END></DATE_END>
</ExportList>
</Body></Envelope>
```

The XML file I want to construct:

```
<Envelope>
<Body>
<ExportList>
<LIST_ID></LIST_ID>
<EXPORT_TYPE></EXPORT_TYPE>
<EXPORT_FORMAT></EXPORT_FORMAT>
<EXPORT_COLUMNS>
            <COLUMN></COLUMN>
            <COLUMN></COLUMN>
            <COLUMN></COLUMN>
            <COLUMN></COLUMN>
</EXPORT_COLUMNS>
</ExportList>
</Body>
</Envelope>
```

Here is my C# code:

```
ListTableExportFormat exportFormat = ListTableExportFormat.CSV;
ExportType exportType = ExportType.ALL;

var reportResponse = client.ExportList(
new SilverpopServiceReference.sessionheadertype { sessionid = session.SESSIONID },
new SilverpopServiceReference.ExportListRequestType
{
            LIST_ID = listID,
            EXPORT_TYPE = exportType,
            EXPORT_FORMAT = exportFormat,
            <WON'T ALLOW TO ADD COLUMN TAGS HERE AS IT DOESN'T RECOGNISE THEM>

});
```

The error I get is: SilverpopServiceReference.ExportListRequestType' does not contain a definition for 'COLUMN'

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the wsdl, `ExportListRequestType` does not have a COLUMNS member, so you can not do what you are trying to do with the `ExportList` method. I did find that there is a method named `RawRecipientDataExport` that takes a `RawRecipientDataExportRequestType`, which does have a COLUMNS member, as well as all the other properties of `ExportListRequestType`. Try changing your code to use `RawRecipientDataExport` and see if that gets you what you want.

```
var reportResponse = client.RawRecipientDataExport(
new SilverpopServiceReference.sessionheadertype { sessionid = session.SESSIONID },
new SilverpopServiceReference.RawRecipientDataExportRequestType
{
            LIST_ID = listID,
            EXPORT_TYPE = exportType,
            EXPORT_FORMAT = exportFormat,
            COLUMNS = <YOU CAN DO THIS NOW>

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mike, did not work unfortunately. What if I edited the SilverpopReference.cs file and added the extra fields in, would that work? (I did attempt it with little luck, but maybe I missed something out?).

Comment: Didn't work. I get a an error saying "Schema Validation processing failed"

Comment: What is the error you get when you try my suggestion? When it comes to SOAP web services the wsdl is the law. The wsdl you reference does not indicate that ExportListRequestType has a COLUMNS member. If you have some other documentation that says ExportListRequestType has a COLUMNS member, then the documentation is wrong, or you have the wrong wsdl. Using this wsdl, there is nothing you can do to make this work.